# MIDletPascal

Tags: pascal, delphi

Что такое MIDletPascal? Я на телефоне запустил какую-то игру, там по-английски написано "Приложение было создано незарегистрированной версией MIDletPascal". Что это такое? 
Как я понял, это типо Паскаль для разработки игр на телефоне. 
И ещё вопрос, раз есть MIDletPascal, то может быть есть MIDletDelphi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [MIDletPascal](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDletPascal) — это язык программирования с паскалеподобным синтаксисом, предназначенный для написания программ для мобильных телефонов (мидлетов).

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем правильно.

Это если ты не знаешь JAVA то пиши на бейсике или паскале.

В том числе **MIDletPascal** ты пишешь все как на паскале, потом компилятор делает из паскаля в JAVA байткод, ну и тестишь на эмуляторе.

Собственно **MIDletDelphi** - не существует.

Comment: Ясно, тогда ещё вопрос: Можно ли использовать модули, как в паскале?

Comment: Ну это уже не ко мне, скорее всего да, но не думаю что все.